# How to store key/values of an array buffer as they arrive?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

So, I'm using the cordova-plugin-ble-central to read data from my HM10's (BLE module) UART TX/RX characteristic.

The plugin returns an ArrayBuffer when you read, but  my HM10 sends the data 20 bytes at a time, and my code is only picking up the trailing array.

For example, if you send from the computer: `123456789012345678905`

You would only recieve on the phone's ArrayBuffer: `5`

```
    this.ble.read(this.peripheral.id, 'ffe0', 'ffe1').then(
  buffer => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.readMessage = this.arrayBufferToString(buffer); })
  });

}

arrayBufferToString(buffer){

var bufView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var length = bufView.length;
var result = '';
var addition = 19;

for(var i = 0;i<length;i+=addition){

    if(i + addition > length){
        addition = length - i;
    }
    result += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, 
bufView.subarray(i,i+addition));
}

return result;

}
```

To no avail. :(

How can I take a function's return, that's returning various ArrayBuffers in very fast millisecond increments (20 bytes at a time), and add all the values into one "final" ArrayBuffer, to then be turned into a string?

If you can help answer this question, you'll be my hero. I've spent over 15 hours on it so far. I figured out how to send data in 20 byte increments, but not receive.

Visual example (assuming my HC10 sends a 40 byte transmission):

```
ArrayBuffer X = bytes 0-19 values (from 0-.01 seconds)
ArrayBuffer X = bytes 19-29 different values (from .01 seconds to .02 seconds)
ArrayBuffer X = bytes 29-39 (from .02 seconds to .03 seconds)
```

Here's what the developer of the plugin suggest I do, but I can't do "innerHTML" with Ionic, since it uses ngZones. Or can I?

Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: What is the expected result of `i+=addition`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, everyone. I'm time poor this week.

Here's the answer I figured out for myself:

Ionic 3.x, Angular, BLE plugin of your choice, etc. etc.

```
logData = ' ';

onConnected(peripheral) {  

this.ngZone.run(() => {
  this.peripheral = peripheral;
          this.setStatus('Connected to ' + peripheral.name || peripheral.id);
    });

   this.ble.startNotification(this.peripheral.id, 'ffe0', 'ffe1').subscribe(
       buffer => {
      var s = this.arrayBufferToString(buffer);
        if (s.match('/')) {
        this.logData = s;
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.readMessage = this.logData; })
    } else {
        this.logData += s;
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.readMessage = this.logData; })
}
  });

    this.ble.read(this.peripheral.id, 'ffe0', 'ffe1').then(
  buffer => {
      var s = this.arrayBufferToString(buffer);
        if (s.match('/')) {
        this.logData = s;
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.readMessage = this.logData; })
    } else {
        this.logData += s;
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.readMessage = this.logData; })
}
  });

}

clear(box) {
    this.logData = '';
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.readMessage = ''; })
}
```

And on your HTML document (for 'fancy' debugging):

```
<ion-card>
<ion-card-header>
<ion-icon name="md-cloud-download" item-start></ion-icon>
Data Recieved  <button ion-button round outline (click)="clear(box)">Clear</button>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
<pre>{{ readMessage }}</pre>
</ion-card-content>
```